# How to get AppBar height programmatically?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm coding a mobile application and I need to find how to get the "appbar" height (which can change from a device to another). I searched a lot but couldn't find any answer.
I already did this to get the "action bar" height :

```
val resources: Resources = this.resources
        val resourceId: Int = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android")
        val lengthNavBar = if (resourceId > 0) {
            resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId)
        } else 0
```

I thought that maybe it would be similar for the action bar, but nothing worked.
Just to be clear, to me the app bar is that :

[image]

And it can be that depending on the device : (That's why I need a dynamic value)

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: And why you need to know that value? These screenshots are not even full-screen.

Comment: Because somewhere in my app I get the rootview as a Bitmap, like a screenshot, and I want to remove the bars on top. So I need to get their height. Thank you for your answer though, I'll look it up tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That part's called the **status bar** it's [usually 24dp high](https://material.io/design/platform-guidance/android-bars.html#status-bar), but with notched diplays like that one it's at least the height of the notch:

> In portrait orientation with no special flags set, the status bar must extend to at least the height of the cutout.

[Here's the guidance on dealing with cutouts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/display-cutout) - basically you probably shouldn't be worrying about the height at all. By default you can just pretend it's not there, if you need to control it and display your own content in there, there are flags you can set. If you do need the value:

> Avoid hard-coding the status bar height, as this can lead to overlapping or cut-off content. Where possible, use [WindowInsetsCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/WindowInsetsCompat) to retrieve the status bar height and determine the appropriate padding to apply to your content.

Comment: Also think that this value is irrelevant, because it's outside of the application's view-port. If something matters, then it's only the remaining height, which the application has available to display something.

Comment: You can display content within that area, that's why there's guidance about handling it. Plus transparent status bars and "immersive mode"s have been a thing for a long time. It just depends on whether you need to display your own content in there, or if you can ignore it

Comment: For special display modes it might play a role, but not for what the screenshots show.

Comment: Thank you for the links, it helped me a lot! I found a way to avoid dealing with that bar, thanks to you :)

Answer (score 1):

The first one picture isn't even part of the application, but it's the system UI. One could obtain the value from the rendered component, but the system UI's status-bar's height is rather irrelevant.

The area, where it reads "Accueil", should be `?android:attr/actionBarSize` or `android.R.attr.actionBarSize`, which defaults to `56dp`.